# jquery ajax request returning entire HTML content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

So I am attempting to return errors from my server-side php request but its returning the entire pages HTML content. I have a login script that does the same thing and works so am beginning to get extremely frustrated.

I hope someone can help me.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form id="register-form">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="off" /></p>
    <p><input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" /></p>
    <p><input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" placeholder="Confirm Password" autocomplete="off" /></p>
    <!-- DISPLAY ERRORS -->
    <p id="error" class="text-danger"></p>
    <input id="register-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="registerBtn" value="Register Now" />
</form>
```

the AJAX request:

```
<script>
        $('#register-btn').click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();

            var username = $('#username').val();
            var email = $('#email').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            var passwordConfirm = $('#passwordConfirm').val();

            $.post("register.php", { username: username, email: email, password: password, passwordConfirm: passwordConfirm }, function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                //$('#error').html(data);
            });
        });
</script>
```

And the PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['email']) && empty($_POST['password']) && empty($_POST['passwordConfirm'])){

    $username           = trim($_POST['username']);
    $email              = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password           = trim($_POST['password']);
    $passwordConfirm    = trim($_POST['passwordConfirm']);

    if(empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordConfirm)){ 
        echo 'All fields are required.';
        exit;
    }else if ($member->member_exists($username) === true) {
        echo 'That username is already taken.';
    }
    exit;
}
```

Comment: @Baldrs It is. Does that matter?

Comment: Don't render other things other than your message on register.php or use json.

Comment: It is actually run in an iframe on top of my home page

Comment: @NicholasLaw It does. You shoud separate html from processing `$_POST` data. PHP outputs anything regardless of request type. And your code with `exit` is probably AFTER html being output, not BEFORE.

Comment: @Baldrs I separated the HTML and AJAX from the PHP and now its working. Thank you. Now I'm not sure why my login script all ran of one page.